# Не подключаются по Wi-Fi компьютер и iPhone к модему Asus RT-AC51U

Tags: wifi, модемы

Модем Asus RT-AC51U. На телефонах (на платформе Android) интернет есть, подключается спокойно, а на компьютерах, и на iphonе нет, пишет "без доступа к интернету",(соединяюсь по wi-fi), помогите пожалуйста советом, что и где можно посмотреть в настройках?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пароли там на два диапазона ставятся.
айфон наверняка ломится на 5ГГц - проверь там настройки.
компы тоже по Wi-Fi - возможно то же на 5ГГц.
Попробуй комп по проводу если есть куда втыкать :)
ну и помни - антена 5ГГц внутри, радиус действия смешной - 2 стены может не пробить.
ну и напоследок - стоковая прошивка ужасно глючная. Все кого знаю прошились на Подавана :) https://bitbucket.org/padavan/rt-n56u/downloads/
Сходи на 4PDA - там есть раздел про твой "модем" и инструкция как прошить альтернативную прошивку - "и да прибудет с тобой сила, юный подаван" :)
https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=712598&st=100

Answer (score 0):

Решилась проблема таким образом, вообщем связался с провайдером, оказалось что проблема с их стороны, они поставили какое-то ограничение на мак-адреса, и поэтому мне морочили голову, а теперь проблема исчезла)